# Sympy solve intersection line circle--->why AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'subs'

Tags: sympy

```
#sympy solve intersection line circle---> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'subs'
from sympy import *
var('v0 x y x0 y0 r a b c')
v=solve([(x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2-r**2,a*x+b*y+c],[x,y])
print(v[0].subs({x0:3.0,y0:2.0,r:5.0,aa:3.0,bb:2.0,cc:-16.0}))
print(v[1].subs({x0:3.0,y0:2.0,r:5.0,aa:3.0,bb:2.0,cc:-16.0}))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File ""C:/xxx.py"", line 4, in <module>"
#     print(v[0].subs({x0:3.0,y0:2.0,r:5.0,aa:3.0,bb:2.0,cc:-16.0}))
# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the call so `solve` this way is a list of tuples -- Python tuples -- that don't understand `subs`. But if you convert them to `Tuple`, they will:

```
>>> from sympy import Tuple
>>> Tuple(*v[0]).subs({x0:3.0,y0:2.0,r:5.0,a:3.0,b:2.0,c:-16.0})
(6.42713674378941, -1.64070511568412)
```

Did you also know that you can define geometric objects with SymPy and find their intersections?

```
>>> from sympy import Circle, Line
>>> Circle((3,2),5).intersection(Line(3*x+2*y-16))
[Point2D(48/13 - 4*sqrt(79)/13, 32/13 + 6*sqrt(79)/13),
 Point2D(4*sqrt(79)/13 + 48/13, 32/13 - 6*sqrt(79)/13)]
>>> [i.n(2) for i in _]
[Point2D(0.96, 6.6), Point2D(6.4, -1.6)]
```

That 2nd point should look familiar :-)